# print a special column in table

Tags: awk

Given this table:

```
Employee
--
firstname    
lastname
salary
age
```

I want to print the first name if it's started by the letter "a", also I want to print the name of `employee` who has a `salary` more than $200 and less than $1,000.

Comment: If you want help with homework, post your best effort at a solution.

Comment: Formatted the table, (I'm just assuming its called something like Employee) and removed the email. Replies are suppose to be posted on the site so everyone can benefit, please don't ask people to email you directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can implement your first requirement:

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^a/) print $1; }' <file name>
```

Second one, salary, can be done in the same manner by adding additional if clause